# Kotlin: How do I filter a List of Strings with subSequence and do not filter out those whose length is less than subSequence requires?

Tags: android, kotlin

So right now I have a list of Strings like so
`{a, b, c, d, Justin, Connor, BYE1, BYE2}`

Right now I am trying to filter out strings in the list with "BYE" in subSequence(0,3). However, if I just type that, I will get an error due to the fact there are strings in the list with less length like `a`. If I add a length checker of `>= 3`, then a,b,c,d do not show up on the filtered list. How do I make it so the end filtered list is `{a,b,c,d,Justin,Connor}`?

As for the code I am using, it is really just one line:

```
//currentList = {a, b, c, d, Justin, Connor, BYE1, BYE2}

var filteredList: List<String> = currentList.filter { s -> (s.length >= 3 && s.subSequence(0,3) != "BYE") }
```

Comment: Please add your kotlin code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    fun filterList() {
        val list = listOf(
            "a",
            "b",
            "c",
            "d",
            "Justin",
            "Connor",
            "BYE1",
            "BYE2"
        )

        val filteredList = list.filter { !it.startsWith("BYE") }

        assertEquals(filteredList.size, 6)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not know about the startsWith function and just what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the solution that is most similar to your first attempt is

```
var filteredList: List = currentList.filter {
        s -> (s.length < 3 || s.subSequence(0,3) != "BYE")
}
```

The first check (`s.length < 3`) will allow any string that is shorter than 3 characters through. The boolean OR (`||`) will short-circuit here for these smaller strings, and the `subSequence` check won't ever run.

The second check (`s.subSequence(0,3) != "BYE"`) will allow any string that doesn't start with `"BYE"`, only of strings that have at least three characters.